# Warning while installing package in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to install the ggplot2 package in R and this is the warning I have been getting:

> Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
>     cannot open the connection
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
>     downloaded length 1040720 != reported length 1152839
>
> 2: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
>
> 3: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
>     cannot open compressed file 'plyr/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

It might be helpful to note that I am using the version 3.1.1. Could you please help me understand what went wrong and how I could resolve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what command did you enter that generated that error?

Comment: @GSee install.packages("ggplot2"), that is all.

Comment: Try `install.packages("ggplot2", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")` or `install.packages("ggplot2", repos="http://cran.rstudio.org")`

Comment: What is the output of `getOption("repos")`?

Comment: @Gsee The output is  CRAN                            CRANextra 
"http://www.freestatistics.org/cran" "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin"

Comment: Well, that's your problem.  How did you set that option?  It should have http:// as part of the addresses

Comment: @Gsee I do not think I did it myself, could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: you could do `options(repos=c(CRAN="@CRAN@"))`.  If you start a fresh R session, does `getOption("repos")` return the same thing?  If so, that suggests it's being set in your .Rprofile or Rprofile.site

Comment: @GSee Now I am getting  CRAN                            CRANextra 
                            "@CRAN@" "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin"

Comment: @Gsee thank you. If you would like to post all your comments as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one, please do so.

Comment: Can help me with this related post please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200536/r-unable-to-install-r-packages-cannot-open-the-connection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the comments we discovered that somehow your `repos` option had been set to a bad value.

`install.packages` has an argument called `repos` that can be used to specify where to find the package that you'd like to install.  If you specify a valid value, it should just work.  e.g. you shouldn't get the error if you do this: `install.packages("ggplot2", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

If you do not provide a value, it will look at the `repos` option.  See `getOption("repos")` to see what is set.  In your case it was

```
                     CRAN                 CRANextra 
"freestatistics.org/cran" "stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin"
```

neither of which are valid URLs.

You can change the value of the `repos` option like this

```
options(repos=c(CRAN="@CRAN@", 
                CRANextra="http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin"))
```

Comment: see also the `repos` section of `?options` as well as `?setRepositories`

Comment: Can help me with this related post please? It is same as the above but my CRAN is already US. site. But still I get this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200536/r-unable-to-install-r-packages-cannot-open-the-connection