# 'No such file or directory' warning: parameters (1)/DESCRIPTION

Tags: r

I'm getting this warning every time I install a package and sometimes when I just load one with `library()`:

```
Warning message:
In readLines(file, skipNul = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/<my folders...>/R/parameters (1)/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Anyone know what that file is and how I can restore it and/or make these warnings go away?

Comment: Have you looked at the related questions? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26086134/8366499) seems to have the same error message

Comment: @divibisan Oh that's strange, I looked at posts that came up when I entered the title of my post but didn't see that one. Thank you

Comment: @divibisan Actually it turns out that the solutions in that thread did not work. Sadly I don't have a reproducible way to get the warning since it seems to mainly come up when I install new packages, and I don't have an infinite number of new packages to install